# What is the conjugate prior for the Von Mises distribution's precision

Tags: bayesian, conjugate-prior, von-mises-distribution

Does the Von Mises distribution have a conjugate prior for its precision/variance?

Update:
The concentration parameter $\kappa$ (Kappa) seems to control the variance of the Von Mises distribution. If $\kappa = 0$, the distribution is uniform, and for $\kappa > 0$ the distribution becomes more concentrated around its mean. What would be a conjugate prior for Kappa?

Comment: Do you mean the variance as in the expected squared deviation from the mean:  $1 - I_1(\kappa)/I_0(\kappa)$, or do you mean the dispersion parameter $\kappa$?  (See the Wikipedia page for notation if unclear:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_distribution )

Comment: @jbowman Apologies. I've updated the question to be more accurate. I need a conjugate prior for Kappa.

Answer (score 3):

A conjugate prior for the concentration parameter $\kappa$ can be any distribution of the form
$$
p(\kappa | a,b) = \frac{\exp(b \kappa)}{I_0(\kappa)^a} \frac{f(\kappa)}{Z(a,b)}
$$
Here $a$ and $b$ are the parameters of the prior. $Z$ is the normalizer. $f$ can be any positive function that does not depend on $a$ and $b$.  Multiplying by a von Mises likelihood function only changes $a$ and $b$, therefore it is a conjugate prior.  Also see [Finding the Location of a Signal: A Bayesian Analysis](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2288846).

Comment: What is $Z$? What are $a$ and $b$? What is $f$?  It can't be arbitrary, for then you would merely be stating (in an overly complicated way) that *any* distribution with positive support can be a conjugate prior.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are the parameters of the prior. $Z$ is the normalizer. $f$ can be any positive function that does not depend on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: You seem to describe *any* (two-parameter) prior, not a conjugate prior.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior): if the posterior distribution $p(\theta \mid x)$ is in the same probability distribution family as the prior probability distribution $p(\theta )$, the prior and posterior are then called conjugate distributions, and the prior is called a conjugate prior for the likelihood function $p(x\mid \theta )$.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate that the posterior for such an arbitrary prior is always a von Mises distribution?

Comment: The posterior for $\kappa$ will not be a von Mises distribution.  $\kappa$ is just a positive number, it doesn't live on the circle.

Comment: Correct me if I wrong but I think that if $p(\kappa|a,b)$ is a conjugate prior for the von Mises distribution, then it means that the **posterior** will also be of the form $p(\kappa|a',b')$ (and not von Mises).